# How to improve baby finger's extension and flexion? How to relax it? How to stretch it?

Tags: stretching, hands, fingers, relaxation

My baby finger has not become relaxed enough due to wrong technique in tennis, too much stress on it and more [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/safe-volley-grip-and-serving-grip-in-tennis). The only moment I can feel the toughness is when I am totally relaxed like after sleeping so it does not limit my activities at all but I don't want to get it bad neither so important to learn to get it more relaxed. So

> *How can I improve baby finger's extension and flexion? How to relax it and how to stretch it?*

**Hand's 2-5 fingers flexion/extension**

> According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAztG_tRWVY), normal ROM values are 85-105 degrees for the flexion and 20-30 degrees for the extension. In contrast, my ROM values are 85 for the flexion and 70 degrees for the extension.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

**Related threads**

1. [Preparing fingers for intensive sports requiring hands a lot?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16392/preparing-fingers-for-intensive-sports-requiring-hands-a-lot)
2. [Safe volley grip and serving grip in tennis](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4609/safe-volley-grip-and-serving-grip-in-tennis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can train the twisting muscle by doing tricep training where you lift a bar above your head and let it go behind your back over your head. Now the key is the grip: you need to inverse your grip to get the twisting muscles activated! I was able to recover from the continuous pain in the twisting muscle caused by golf, tennis and climbing by inventing the totally new training with **bar over the head with inverse grip (for the traditional tricep training)**!

Basically the other muscle group can be seen as opposing muscle group on the other side: anterior/posterior pair

[image]

where I **removed the pain on the other side by forearm training** illustrated in this answer [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/4625/630).