# Leukonychia with an athletic person, how to treat it? Zinc?

Tags: diet, vo2max

Vo2max training result into transparent urea, not sure why perhaps not enough eating things and getting/absorbing minerals -- apparently particularly Zinc. I have [Leukonychia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukonychia) (white spots in nails). It is caused either by the lack of minerals or body not absorbing things enough aka [Hypoalbuminemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoalbuminemia). I take this multivitamin [here](http://www.fitnesstukku.fi/5/fi/artiklar/only-one-60-tabletter) containing: Magnesium 100mg (27%), Kalium 200mg (10%), Zinc 10mg (100%), Iron 14mg (100%), Copper 1mg (100%), Mangan 2mg (100%), Iodine 150µg (100%), Chromium 40µg (100%) and Selen 55 µg (100%). I feel so much better on the morning when I take minerals, it wakes me up (not D-vitamin doing this). This means that my body is lacking minerals apparently or they are not absorbed or my intensity of training requires even more minerals. You can see that I am trying to take 100% RDA/RDI of all necessary vitamins/minerals. It looks that I need more.

**How to treat Leukonychia with an athletic person?**

Comment: Other than you say the phrase "VO2 max training", how is this fitness related?

Comment: This is wildly off-topic. We aren't doctors.

Comment: Nutritions (vitamins, food, etc) and rest (rest days, training profile) are far more important to proper training than just moving your limbs -- match the nutritions/rest to training and you go far. Is this off-topicness actually some sort of bodyphobic reaction or low self-esteem reaction? I cannot understand. Vo2max has such a specific nutrition/rest profile: stress to nerves, losing minerals, extra rest, etc. Eat, rest, sport and repeat -- not in any other order!  Dot, forever and always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal urea color differs between transparent to yellow. 
The color of the urea is not relevant in the yellow perspective.
Red, blue, purple, brown/orange, black are all urine colors denoting some sort of disease/injury process.

You just drink much if you have transparent urea - good thing! 
Your kidneys are working well.
If you suspect you have some problem with your kidneys, monitor the urination amounts during night time vs day time. 
If those two amounts equal, then you have some problem in your kidneys.

Leuconychia is completely normal thing.

Like I discussed with you, your Zinc deficiency is caused by other things related in your gastrointestinal system (celiac disease). 
To recover from it, requires 100% gluten-free diet and takes time even one year if bad.

Follow balanced training plan (example below) with physical training and specific sport training

- 2-3 training (tennis)
- swimming/stretching once per week
- power training 1-2 per week (decrease this if other heavy sessions)

where the appropriate amounts depends on your exercise level during your life (childhood, ...).

Do power training when you do not have difficult training plan. 
Do enough recovery

- always enough pulling and push movements - use those metallic/rubber coils or strings
- put legs to the air next the wall sometimes
- gymnastics of legs (stepping on your feet - little movements)

Do have enough **nutrition fiber** and vitamin B in your diet

- water melon, orange, porridge (oats)
- gluten-free diet can lead to vitamin B deficiency so take your multivitamin

The recovery of the nervous system takes much time (many months). 
Please, pay attention to terms

- overtraining syndrome
- ibuprofen + exercise (if you take this)
- supercompensation
- and particularly Womba training periodisation

Do not fast when doing sport

- Ca2+ is the most important buffer
- ketone bodies accumulate in our body if you fast
- our body buffers this by Calcium
- our body takes it from bones
- you break your bones if you do sport and fast at the same time

Feel free to ask private more.

Comment: Red, blue, purple, brown/orange, black are all urine colors denoting some sort of disease/injury process.

Comment: @JohnP Yes, you are right. I simplified in colors to different colors of yellow. Thank you for your comment! Please, add reference if you can.

Answer (score -1):

First, micronutrient deficiency is very rare, it's mostly something that vitamin pill manufacturers are scaring people with. But it can't hurt, right? Except that in total, we are wasting billions of dollars on something has most often has no effect.

There are possible exceptions though, people with very bad eating habits (like only eating pasta), uninformed vegans and women who get too little iron. Not sure if being very active actually leads to deficiencies, havn't seen any studies on it at least.

Do not underestimate the power of placebo, it probably causes your good mornings, enjoy it while it lasts.

Afaik, there is also quite a lot of dispute about the bioavailability of minerals and vitamins in supplements. Perhaps you could try eating better food with higher mineral levels? Some foods containing zinc are red meat, liver in particular, celery, beans and nuts.

Also, "Zinc supplements should only be ingested when there is zinc deficiency or increased zinc necessity (e.g. after surgeries, traumata or burns). [181] [182] Persistent intake of high doses of zinc can cause copper deficiency." According to wikipedia.

Go to a doctor and check if you actually have any deficiencies.

Comment: I take all minerals at the same time, also 1mg Copper (100% of needed daily dosage).

Comment: This is a poor answer to a bad question.