# How to make scar tissue due to blisters heal faster in hands after tennis/fencing/climbing?

Tags: tennis, hands, fencing

[image]

I got blister just to the point that holds a foil i.e. index finger. It irritates me in tennis, fencing and climbing.

**What are best methods to recover from scar tissue due to blister?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Different methods**

> 1. Parafin-style thing such as ClimbOn (as shown in question) acts as a good massage tool and protection
> 2. different lotions such as Nivea lotions to heal it faster: getting the fats/ingredients externally around the injured area, the skin will absorb it and it can heal faster.
> 3. Irritating/massaging: merging scar tissue with healthy tissue, instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYs_UXKvjIE&feature=youtu.be). Please notice that the scar tissue heals far slower with older people.
> 4. Exercise more: you can increase the recovery rate by exercising more (more blood flow)